# java keystore at client site

Tags: java, security

I have a web application that I install at client sites.  The app needs a keystore (for SAML integration)

Should I be creating a single keystore and deploying to all client sites, or should I create a keystore per client site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should defenitely create a separate certifikate/keystore for each client. Re-using the same client side certificate on many clients is easy when it comes to the initial distribution, but creates a lot of problems when you have to issue new certificates, revoke certificates etc.

In SAML, the client side certificate is also used to identify the issuer of the SAML assertion. If you re-use the same client side certificate, all your clients can impersonate each other.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on requirements and resources but here are my 2 cents: I would create keystore per client for the security reasons. In the worst case scenario if keystore is lost (stolen, server hacked & such), it can't be abused across my entire client base.